# What, exactly, does physical resistance protect against?

Tags: diablo-iii

Does it apply for all non-elemental attacks, or is there more going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All damage has a type. Damage that is not associated with a specific element is of the "physical" type. Physical resist specifically protects against this type of damage.